# Run Two Programs Off The Same Procfile

Tags: heroku, procfile

I have 2 discord bot programs, one is python code and the other is nodejs. I was wondering if in the procfile, like when you say worker: python ___, is there a way so that it runs both my python file and codejs file at the same time? Right now I can only get either or to run.

My procfile right now is just:
worker: python log.py
worker: node bot.js

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your Procfile being:

```
worker: python log.py
worker: node bot.js
```

You do:

```
worker: python log.py & node bot.js & wait -n
```

see: https://help.heroku.com/CTFS2TJK/how-do-i-run-multiple-processes-on-a-dyno

Comment: Thank you so much. What if i wanted to use another nodejs program as well? would it be:

`worker: python log.py & node.bot.js & node.bot2.js & wait -n`

And also if my program is in a folder, would it be something like:

`worker: python /folder/log.py`

Thank you