# Is there a way to have two processes running on a Heroku deployment?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, plotly-dash

I have a dash app and the easiest way to deploy it is via Heroku. I have two parts of my application, a streamer, and a dash frontend. The streamer stream tweets from twitter via the tweepy API, parses out the relevant information, creates the SQLite database if it does not exist, and then interest the tweets into the database. The dash frontend just grabs the tweets from the database from descending Unix timestamp (i.e. display the most recent tweets) and displays them on a live graph where the user can type in a term and see the live sentiment for that term.

I know in the Procfile you define what process you want running on the dyno via `web: gunicorn app: server` where `app.py` is the python file that contains the `app.run_server`, but I need the streamer to be running concurrently with the dash frontend and they are in two different .py files in my project.

I tried putting the code in `streamer.py` that handles the twitter authentication, runs the streamer, and creates the SQLite DB if it does not exists in a `def main():` and then importing that `def main():` into the `app.py`, but when I run `app.py` it just runs the streamer and never runs `app.run_server`.

Is there a way to run these two processes concurrently on Heroku?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62529869/run-two-programs-off-the-same-procfile/62531358#62531358). You will run into another problem. Your sqlite db will be wiped due to [Heroku's ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)

Comment: Thank you, and that's okay. I want the database to be wiped every 24 hours anyway. So my Procfile will look like this @TinNguyen `worker: app.py & streamer.py & wait -n
`?